# Does The Riemann-Siegel function define a unitary operator In Complex Hilbert space?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, riemann-zeta

I have tried to define Riemann zeta function for $ Re(s)=\frac12 $ in Hilbert space 
$ H=l^2(\mathbb{C, ds})$ using the well known formula of [Riemann-Siegel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function) which it is defined as : $\zeta(0.5+it)=Z(t)\exp(-i \theta(t)) $ for every positive real $t$  with $ Z(t)$  is $Z$-function , I have tried to show that Riemann zeta function is [unitary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator) using the interesting property of Hilbert space which is inner product , I have accrossed the problem about rate growth of integral square of Z-function which  it is $ t \log t $ is not bounded for to $t\to \infty $ the latter Botched me to juge wether $\zeta(0.5+it)$ is a unitary operator or not any idea to show that ?

**Note:01** In Riemann Siegel function we have :$\exp(-i \theta(t)) $ present unitary operator

> > **Edit**:let us define my operator which i want it act on Riemann-siegel function .
> >     let 
> >     $W(t)=\exp (itH)$, so 
> >     $$
> > W(t) W(-t)=1\!\! 1,
> > $$
> >     We  could define it as :
> >     $$
> > U(t)\equiv W(t) ~~e^{-\beta H/2},
> > $$

Comment: @reuns , for example if i ask if the Forrier transform define a unitary operator in Hilbert space the answer w'd be yes , and in my question here i ask about Riemann Siegle function if it could be a unitary operator because many functions could define operators  in some defined spaces

Comment: You didn't define any linear operator. A function isn't a linear operator.

Comment: if RH is true the titled question holds , but the problem if RH dosn't hold i meant for non trivial zeros probaly you meant zeta is not linear in that case

Comment: Come on... The Riemann-Siegel function is a function, not a linear operator. The Fourier transform is a linear operator $L^2(\Bbb{R}) \to L^2(\Bbb{R})$, same for the derivative operator, they send functions to functions. Do you see the difference ?

Comment: There is no fundamental difference between an operator and a function.
If I want to multiply two numbers together, I can use the multiplication operator (A x B) or I can define a function; F(A,B) = A x B
The difference is that if you want to do a common operation like addition or multiplication, it’s quicker and easier to use an operator rather than defining functions.

Comment: If there is "no fundamental difference" then tell me what is your operator...

Comment: Do you see the difference between a matrix and a vector ? Here it is the same.

Comment: @reuns , pleas look well in the definition of Riemann-Sigel function in the RHS the exponential form present unitary operator

Comment: Do you know what is a matrix ?

Comment: Product of 2 vector this is the reason let me ask wether Riemann siegel function unitary operator since it includes its form

Comment: No a matrix isn't the product of two vectors

Comment: Probably i take a look at z(t)/(zeta(0.5+it)) =exp(-i thet(t))

Comment: @reuns Now, Matrices are vectors - from the vector space of matrices - but not all vectors are matrices. Looking at it from an algebraic perspective, matrices have this exciting double life of being a rectangle of numbers at day, and a linear function at night, whereas ordinary vectors (the one-column-of-numbers kind, not in the more general element-of-a-vector-space kind) usually don't have a side business of being a linear operator.

Comment: @reuns, is it conceivable that the questioner is wanting to make a multiplication operator or something similar?

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes I'm quite sure this is what he means but I wanted to see if he could define his operator or explain why he is stuck. Plus in wiki/unitary_operator they mention C^* algebras so he can believe this applies only to $C^0(X)$

Comment: @paulgarrett, I have defined the requerd opertaor

Answer (score 0):

> Again you didn't define any linear operator.

If $f$ is continuous  $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$ and $\forall t, |f(t)| =1$ and $$A(g)(t) = g(t)f(t)$$ then $A$ is an unitary linear operator $L^2(\Bbb{R}) \to L^2(\Bbb{R})$ because $$\|A(g)\|_{L^2} =\int_{-\infty}^\infty| A(g)(t)|^2dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty| g(t)|^2dt= \|g\|_{L^2}$$ for all $g\in L^2(\Bbb{R}) $.